# what to do for non present DIV tag. Using Selenium & Python

Tags: selenium, automation, python-3.8

I'm trying to extract information with help of selenium and python  from this container "PROJECT INFORMATION"  //www.rera.mp.gov.in/view_project_details.php?id=aDRYYk82L2hhV0R0WHFDSnJRK3FYZz09
but while do this I was getting this error

Unable to locate element:
{"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/article/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SfRO.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SfRO.png)/**div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SfRO.png)**/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SfRO.png)"}

after studying about it I found that this highlighted div is missing and there are many places in this container where div is missing. How am I supposed to do that? I want information only from the right side of the table
[image]

**MY CODE:**

```
for c in [c for c in range(1, 13) if (c == True)]:            

    row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div["+ str(c) +"]/div[2]").text

    print(row, end="   ")
    print("     ")
else:
    print('NoN')
```

**error:**

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.106)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields highlighted are two different cases. While for "Registration Number" the required `div` does not exist, for "Proposed End Date" it exists but contains only white space.

Give this a try instead of the `for c...` loop. It should handle both cases.

```
#find parent element
proj_info=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-md-12 box']")

#find all rows in parent element
proj_info_rows = proj_info.find_elements_by_class_name('row')

for row in proj_info_rows:
    try:
        if row.find_element_by_class_name('col-md-8').text.strip() == "":
            print(f"{row.find_element_by_class_name('col-md-4').text} contains only whitespace {row.find_element_by_class_name('col-md-8').text}")
            print('NaN')
        else:
            print(row.find_element_by_class_name('col-md-8').text)
    except SE.NoSuchElementException:
        print('NaN')
```

You need this import:

```
from selenium.common import exceptions as SE
```

Comment: Forgot the add the import.